# Iterate through Dictionary over all levels

Tags: ios, swift, loops, dictionary

I have a data structure in a Dictionary which looks like this:

```
- device
   - type
   - isActive
   - Data
      - Manufacturer 
      - Build Date
      - Power
      ...
   - Example
```

Now if I create a For Loop it only shows me the Values of the First level which means

```
type, isActive, Data, Example


for (key, value) in value {

}
```

All below Data like Build Date or Power is Missing - how can I irritate through this levels also?

Comment: you need something like `func displayData(data) { ... }` and if `value` is once again a dictionary, call `displayData(value)` *recursively*.

Comment: "Irritate through Dictionary?" LOL. I think you mean "**Iterate** through dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate nested dictionaries with unknown numbers of nesting levels in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526326/how-to-iterate-nested-dictionaries-with-unknown-numbers-of-nesting-levels-in-swi)

Comment: What is it you want to do with your nested dictionaries? Log their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Dictionary with type [String:Any], function to flatten it will be something like:

```
    func flatten(_ obj:[String:Any]) -> [String:Any] {
        var result = [String:Any]()
        for (key, val) in obj {
            if let v = val as? [String:Any] {
                result = result.merging(flatten(v), uniquingKeysWith: {
                    $1
                })
            }
            //I also included initial value of internal dictionary
            /if you don't need initial value put next line in 'else'
            result[key] = val 
        }
        return result
    }
```

To use that:

```
    let d:[String:Any] = [
        "test1":1,
        "test2":2,
        "test3":[
            "test3.1":31,
            "test3.2":32
        ]
    ]
    let res = flatten(d)
    print(res)
```

> ["test2": 2, "test3.2": 32, "test3.1": 31, "test1": 1, "test3":
> ["test3.2": 32, "test3.1": 31]]

note: dictionaries are not sorted structures

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! Have great evening!

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) problem here.

---

You could *walk* the dictionary level by level:

```
func walk(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        print("\(key): \(value)")
        if let value = value as? [String: Any] {
            walk(dictionary: value)
        }
    }
}
```

You can change `[String: Any]` type with your dictionary type (`NSDictionary`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

As Tomas says, this can be solved with recursion. His "walk" function simply prints the values on separate lines, but with no keys, and not formatting. Here is code that logs nested dictionaries using the structure you outlined:

```
//Define the keys we use in our example
enum keys: String {
    case device
    case type
    case isActive
    case Data
    case Manufacturer
    case BuildDate
    case Power
    case Example
    }

//Create a sample dictionary using those keys and some random values
let dict = [keys.device.rawValue:
                [keys.type.rawValue: "appliance",
                 keys.isActive.rawValue: true,
                 keys.Data.rawValue:
                    [keys.Manufacturer.rawValue: "GE",
                     keys.BuildDate.rawValue: "12/23/96",
                     keys.Power.rawValue: 23,
                    ],
                 keys.Example.rawValue: "Foo"
                ]
]

//Create an extension of Dictionary for dictionaries with String Keys.
extension Dictionary where Key == String {
    
    //Define a function to recursively build a description of our dictionary
    private func descriptionOfDict(_ aDict: [String: Any], level: Int = 0) -> String {
        var output = ""
        var indent: String = ""
        if level > 0 {
            output += "\n"
            for _ in 1...level {
                indent += "   "
            }
        }
        for (key,value) in aDict {
            output += indent + key + ": "
            if let subDict = value as? [String: Any] {
                //If the value for this key is another dictionary, log that recursively
                output +=  descriptionOfDict(subDict, level: level+1)
            } else {
                if let aString = value as? String {
                    output += "\"" +  aString + "\"\n"
                }  else {
                    output += String(describing: value) + "\n"
                }
            }
        }
        return output
    }
    
    //Add a description property for dictionaries
    var description: String  {
        return descriptionOfDict(self)
    }
}


print(dict.description)
```

That outputs:

```
device: 
   isActive: true
   Data: 
      Manufacturer: "GE"
      Power: 23
      BuildDate: "12/23/96"
   Example: "Foo"
   type: "appliance"
```

### Edit:

The above, defining a `String` property `description`, changes the output when you print a `[String:Any]` dictionary. If you don't want that, rename the property `description` to something else like `dictDescription`

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to name it description. The original description property will be inaccessible.

Comment: It was my intention to override the `description` property. By all means call it something else if you don't want to change the default description output. I added a comment to that effect. (I add `customStringConvertible` conformance and a `description` property to my custom classes and structs all the time. It's a very handy debugging aid.)